# \n in Python 3 confusion

Tags: python-3.x, string

I am pretty new at python. So, I get this
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
after running this:

`print (full_name.title()\nfull_name.upper()\nfull_name.lower())`

Any idea why?

Comment: Could you please write the whole code here?

Answer (score 2):

You must separate each string by a comma, and the use quotes around the strings:

```
print(full_name.title(), '\n', full_name.upper(), '\n', full_name.lower())
```

Alternatively, you could first concatenate the fragments, then print the resulting string:

```
string_to_print = full_name.title() + '\n' + full_name.upper() + '\n' + full_name.lower()
print(string_to_print)
```

There are more sophisticated approaches too (`f-strings`, `format`, `__str__`, etc.) that you may want to look up once you have mastered the basics.

Comment: Doesn't worth another answer, you could edit in also the use of string formatting: `"{title}\n{upper}\n{lower}".format(title=full_name.title(), upper=full_name.upper(), lower=full_name.lower()` or the use of new f-strings: `f"{full_name.title()}\n{full_name.upper()}\n{full_name.lower()()}"`

Comment: Thanks, mate. I did it using f'.